# Ajax not working properly with jsp

Tags: ajax, jsp, jstl

I'm new in ajax and I'm trying to inset data in database using ajax and jstl without refreshing page. 
While inserting data it works perfectly but it jumps on action url instead of staying on same page.
Here is my Code
HTML CODE

```
 <form  action="insert.jsp?themesCat=1" method="post" name="themecat" id="themecat">
 <div id="success" style="display:none" class="form-group has-success">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess"><img src="images/admin/upthumb.png"/> One Theme Added Successfully...!!!</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <label>Enter Theme Name:</label>
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" name="themeCatName" id="themeCatName" required="true" title="Enter Thneme Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Button</button>

</form>
```

AJAX CODE

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var themecat = $('#themecat');
            form.submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                                type: form.attr('method'),
                                url: form.attr('action'),
                                data: form.serialize(),
                                success: function () {
                                                $('#success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    return false;
                            });
</script>
```

INSERT.JSP

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.themesCat}">

<c:if test="${not empty param.themeCatName}">
    <c:set var="max" value="1000" />
    <sql:query var="res">Select tID from themes</sql:query>

    <c:forEach items="${res.rows}" var="row">
        <c:if test="${max < row.tID}">
            <c:set var="max" value="${row.tID}" />
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>

    <sql:update var="n">
        Insert into themes 
        values ( 
        ${max + 1},
        '${param.themeCatName}'
        )
  </sql:update>
</c:if>    success</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

- The js probably loaded before the html, try wrapping it inside $(document).ready();
- By the way, where's the declaration of "form" variable in "type: form.attr('method'),"  ?